# Configure multi-word synonyms containing stop words in them in solr search

Tags: solr, stop-words, type-synonyms

I want to configure multi word synonyms having stop words in them like smbs , small to medium business in this case synonyms contains stop words but it should ignore stop word and give the search result but if we search for stop word like to it should return no results

tried this blog https://sease.io/2018/07/combining-synonyms-and-stopwords.html